# Typescript type definitions versions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having issues with type definitions (td) versioning. Could someone explain to me why the current guidelines enforce the use of a version for type definitions for all versions but the latest one and why they don't say anything about specifying a version for type definitions they depend upon?

I'll explain my perplexity: I'm facing the issue that right now, the `browserify` td doesn't work with the latest `node` td (but it works with v0.11.0). Given the current guidelines, how can someone who writes a td that references another one be sure that a new update to the referenced td doesn't brake theirs? I don't see a way right now. As an end user, right now the only solution I've got is to manually change the `browserify` td to reference the `node` version that doesn't break it. It doesn't sound like an ideal scenario to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two interesting sides to this discussion.

The first problem is that the definitions get updated as new versions of the TypeScript language come out with features that make definitions easier and more accurate. A good example of this is union types.

The second problem is that the third party libraries are constantly being updated and the definitions therefore move with the libraries.

If you are using "pretty much the latest of everything" this is all fine, but if you are looking for a combination it will become impossible (i.e. TypeScript 1.1 with jQuery 1.9).

You can usually see the history of a definition by reviewing the changes, so if you need an older version of a library you can find it - but you may stumble across the TypeScript language issue. For example, if you wanted to use a rather old version of a library, you might find the `.d.ts` uses `bool` not `boolean` and needs to be updated before it will compile.

There are two related issues on Definitely Typed relating to this:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/3031

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/2972